# How to initialize component data by calling a service through HttpClient

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I'm seeing dozens of similar posts but none of the solutions worked for me. So please don't answer by sending me to read other posts 'cause I did it before posting here.
I'm trying to initialize a component property by calling a service. here is the component code:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  myData: number[];

  constructor(@Inject(MyService) private myService: MyService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getMyData().subscribe(data => this.myData = data);
}
```

The service code is as follows:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService implements OnInit {
  private numbers: Observable<number[]>;

  constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private http: HttpClient) {}

  getMyData(): Observable<number[]> {
    return this.numbers;
  }

ngOnInit() {
 this.http.post<MyDataResponse> (this.url, new MyDataRequest(100))
   .subscribe(resp => this.numbers = 
   observableOf(resp.data));
}
```

At the runtime I get the following exception:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at .../MyComponent.ngOnInit (...)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:18620)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:19884)
at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:19846)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:20480)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:20440)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (...)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:20432)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:19828)
at callViewAction (core.js:20069
```

So, to resume, the component subscribes to an observable returned by a service by calling a rest endpoint. The rest endpoint works as expected and gets correctle called and returns the right response.
The exception has probably to do with the asynchrounous type of the operation but I don't know how am I supposed to deal with that.
Additionally, I don't need that the operation be asynchrounous but, as surprizing as it might be, I didn't find any way to perform synchrounous rest calls in angular.
Could anyone please shad some more light on this ? Many thanks in advance.
Nicolas

Comment: Just a note to mention that the exception is raised in the ngOnInit() method of the component, not the one of the service. I'm not sure it was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are using the variable `this.numbers`  in `getMyData()` before being the observable, therefore your error of `undefined`.

What you probably wanna do it's something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.numbers =  this.http.post<MyDataResponse> (this.url, new MyDataRequest(100));
}
```